# Mathematica doesn't evaluate an expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, special-functions, numerical-value, expression

I have such a code:

```
A = 1;
ω0 = 5*10^6;
τ0 = 3*10^-3*Sqrt[2/Log[2]]/(5.85*10^3);
s0[t_] = A*E^(-t^2/τ0^2)*Cos[ω0*t];
Es = Integrate[Abs[s0[t]]^2 // ComplexExpand, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Et0[t0_] = Assuming[t0 ∈ Reals, Integrate[Abs[s0[t]]^2 // ComplexExpand, {t, -t0, t0}]];
Solve[Et0[t]/Es - 0.9 == 0, t]
```

Here is a function `s0[t_]` of the signal. `Es`, which is integral of `Abs[s0[t]]^2` over `[-Infinity ; Infinity]` means the energy of the signal. `t0` is a time which gives 90% of `Es` by integrating `Abs[s0[t]]^2` over `[-t0 ; t0]`.

But it doesn't evaluate the last expression. I see such a result:

[image: thing]

This is not what I need. I need normal number (like "4.5", "1e-5", "13.6*10^(-3)" etc). What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Et0[t_]` should be `Et0[t0_]`,  `E[t]/Es` should be `Et0[t]/Es` , but since `s0[t]` still too small, the equations can not be handle.

Comment: @cvgmt , now I get endless running. How do I get result?

Comment: Please state the mathematical problem you are trying to solve. It is not obvious from your code given here.

Comment: @Somos , here is a function `s0[t_] = A*E^(-t^2/τ0^2)*Cos[ω0*t]` of the signal. `Es`, which is integral of `Abs[s0[t]]^2` over `[-Infinity ; Infinity]` means the energy of the signal. `t0` is a time which gives 90% of `Es` by integrating `Abs[s0[t]]^2` over `[-t0 ; t0]`.

Comment: Try `Et0[tlim_] := Integrate[Abs[s0[t]]^2, {t, -tlim, tlim}]; FindRoot[Chop[Et0[tlim]] == 
9/10 Es, {tlim, .8 τ0, .7 τ0, .9 τ0, Evaluated -> False]`, which yields `tlim -> 6.91136*10^-7`.  `Solve` is unable to address this problem.  If this question is reopened, I can provide more detail.

Comment: @bbgodfrey , oh, it really works, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  By the way, you do not need `ComplexExpand` in `Es` either.

Answer (score 3):

I think your expression `E[t]` inside `Solve` should be `Exp[t]`. Try this instead, where I changed that, and the assignment to `t0`:

```
(* Your code *)
A = 1;
ω0 = 5*10^6;
τ0 = 3*10^-3*Sqrt[2/Log[2]]/(5.85*^3);
s0[t_] = A*E^(-t^2/τ0^2)*Cos[ω0*t];
Es = Integrate[Abs[s0[t]]^2 // ComplexExpand, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}];

(* modifications *)
t0 = t /. First@Solve[Exp[t]/Es - 0.9 == 0, t];
Chop@ Integrate[Abs[s0[t]]^2 // ComplexExpand, {t, -t0, t0}]

(* Out: -5.45922*10^-7 *)
```

Comment: That's not it. I need to find `t0` which can give 90% of `Es` by integration over `[-t0 ; t0]`.

Comment: `E[t]` is not `E^(t)`, it is `Et0[t]`. It's just a typo.